# How to properly connect to a database without hardcoding credentials?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So I'm working on a desktop app for admin, clients and guests to look and buy the products I've saved in the database.
The system works well, the user enters his credentials and logs in, but the connection to the database is made with hardcoded credentials, like this:

```
    Public Function CONNECTION_STRING() As String
            Dim myConnectionString As String
            myConnectionString = "server=xxx.xx.xx.x;" _
                & "uid=admin;" _
                & "pwd=123;" _
                & "database=item_db"
            Return myConnectionString
    End Function
```

Is it safe to deliver this app with this being hardcoded? Being it so easy to use Ghidra and read that I mean.
I've read about hashing it, but how will the database login system unhash it? Sorry for being ignorant but I'm learning :/.
Btw the hashing would be bCrypt.

Comment: You should read these credentials from environment variables.

Comment: You certainly shouldn't hard-code the connection string in the application. It should be read from some external source and that source can be encrypted. This is a subject for research on the web, not a site intended for specific issues. If you try something and it doesn't work, that would be the time to ask here.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'm using app.config which will be ignored in github, I'm looking on how to encrypt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not a good way going forward.

You shouldn't have to hardcode the credentials into the application, there are several approaches here:

1. If possible, use native authentication ("Integrated security") to use user's AD credentials against database. This way credentials are not sent or stored in clear text on the client.
2. Prompt user for credentials and use them to authenticate the database connection.
3. Use config file to store the credentials. This is almost as bad as having the credentials in the source, but at least it is a bit more manageable and will keep them out of the VCS.
4. Use backend application server to process the data to prevent users from directly accessing the database. More of an architectural changes.

First two require each user to be granted permissions to connect to database.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer gave me a good idea, looking for a way to store connection credentials in the system the software is being used. In my case all of the computers using the software I'm developing use Microsoft Windows 10, so it's as easy as using [ODBC Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-odbc-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15), a software that allows the storage of connection strings. Since the software is going to be used in an specific building, when we are perfoming the installation we just save the connection string in ODBC Data Sources, and refer it from the source code, in case it doesn't exist in a specific computer it won't connect.

```
Dim con As New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

Public Sub Connect()
        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=THE NAME OF THE DSN CREATED"
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As MySqlClient.MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```